# Find and replace tabs with spaces in LightTable

Tags: lighttable

I have tried using `\t` in the find function but it doesn't work.

I've got some files with tabs in it, and I need to replace the tabs with 4 spaces.

How can I get the find function to recognise tab characters so I can replace them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy your "tab" empty space and paste it into find window.

Nice IDE by my first impression, by the way.

Answer (score 3):

There are two regex search options to accomplish what you want.

For either of these, what you would do is prefix and postfix your search with `/` characters.

```
/\t/
```

### 1. Regex search in the current file

To do this, open the command panel, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>, and type `Find: In current editor` to open the Find Bar.

### 2. Regex search in the current workspace

To do this, open the command panel, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>, and type `Searcher: Show` to open the Workspace Searcher.